# WCAG 2.0 Redundant Links

Tags: website-design, accessibility

I've tried searching but can't seem to find a straight answer regarding redundant links and WCAG compliance.

I have a product collection/category page with a list of products. Each product has a product image, name, price, and Learn More button. The product image and Learn More button both go to the same destination.

```
<div class="product-wrap">
    <div class="product-image">
        <a href="product-page.html"><img src="product-image.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="product-name">
        Sample Product Name
    </div>
    <div class="product-price">
        $29.99
    </div>
    <div class="product-learn-more"
        <a href="product-page.html">Learn More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Based off what I've read having adjacent links go to the same location is not compliant.

I can't link the whole product since I don't want everything clickable so I'm not sure what my options are.

Does anything have any idea how to make this compliant?

Thanks!

Comment: [Cross-posted to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56119331/1591669)

Answer (score 2):

> Based off what I've read having adjacent links go to the same location is not compliant.

Strictly speaking, having redundant links is not a compliance failure.  There is no WCAG success criteria dealing with redundant links.  It's more of a UX decision whether to have them or not.  If you can avoid them, great, but if not, it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

**Get rid of the learn-more button.**  It serves no useful function when it simply duplicates the action of another link.  It would be like having multiple buttons to post, send, reply, submit, etc.  Pick just one.

Comment: I would argue that it provides a call to action that otherwise wouldn't be on the product blocks, as well as gives a clear way to see more details to anyone that is unfamiliar with the idea that the image is likely to be clickable.